# In Angular, can view be loaded in code?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Very simply, after an API call, depending on the return value, how is the appropriate view loaded?  Consider having

```
search.html
views/found.html
views/notfound.html
```

Search's controller makes an AJAX call to a service and gets a good or bad result.  Now I want the appropriate view to load, without user having to click.  I just can't figure out how to do this and have looked at scores of routing/view examples.  I'm using HTML5 mode.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'search.html',
            controller: 'searchCtrl'
        })
        .when('found', {
            templateUrl: 'views/found.html',
            controller: 'foundCtrl'
        })
        .when('notFound', {
            templateUrl: 'views/notFound.html',
            controller: 'notFoundCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'search.html',
            controller: 'searchCtrl'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requiredBase: true
    });
```

And in the controller ..

```
$scope.post = function (requestType, requestData) {
    var uri = 'Search/' + requestType;
    $http.post(uri, requestData)
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.searchResult.ID = response.ID;
            $scope.searchResult.Value = response.Value;
            // how is the view/route loaded without a user click?
            'found';
            return true;
        }).error(function (error) {
            // how is the view/route loaded without a user click?
            'notFound';
            return false;
        });
```

I'm just lost after getting back the response on how to invoke a view within the template.

Comment: Have tried $location.url('found'); but the view doesn't change.

Comment: See the answer below

Comment: Using $location, the URL in address bar changes, but controller does not receive an update notification, so the view does not change.  I need to use code to invoke a view change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `ngRoute` use `$location.path()` instead of `$state.go()`. The `$location.path()` method accepts a url specified in route configuration. E.g.:

```
$location.path('/found');
```

Say your controller is `AppController`, then the complete code will look something like:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .controller('AppController', function ($location, $http) {
     $scope.post = function (requestType, requestData) {
        var uri = 'Search/' + requestType;
        $http.post(uri, requestData)
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.searchResult.ID = response.ID;
                $scope.searchResult.Value = response.Value;
                // how is the view/route loaded without a user click?
                $location.path('/found');
            }).error(function (error) {
                // how is the view/route loaded without a user click?
                $location.path('/notFound');
            });
   });
```

Refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location for api documentation of `$location.path`

Comment: The URL in address bar changes, but the view does not load into the template.  I'm new to Angular, so does this indicate this portion is correct, but my view is not hooked up correctly somehow?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this only edits the displayed location.  It does not appear to perform any action which makes Angular think it should display the view.  The controller never receives a notification that a new URL is being requested.